# Decode kafka consumer msg from string to avro using avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are sending data to Kafka producer as a string and the final output from consumer is in Avro Schema format.

I need to decode the final output using avro schema.Can someone share sample java code to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved: This code will print the consumer messages in the Avro schema format.

```
 props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer","io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
 props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://kafka-.XXX");

 KafkaConsumer<String, avro_schema> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic"));
 //infinite poll loop

 try {
      while (true) {

           ConsumerRecords<String, avro_schema> records = consumer.poll(200L);
           for (ConsumerRecord<String, avro_schema> record : records) {
                   System.out.println(record.value());

           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps -

1.Create the object from the avro schema

```
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema <schema file> <destination>

eg.
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema user.avsc .
```

This will generate the appropriate source files in a package based on the schema's namespace

2. Deserialize using the avro schema and the above generated class
   For example if the above command created source class as User.class then deserialize the data as below

```
private static void deserialize() {
        try {
            // Deserialize Users from disk
            DatumReader<User> userDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(User.class);
            DataFileReader<User> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<User>(new File("users.avro"), userDatumReader);
            User user = null;
            while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
                // Reuse user object by passing it to next(). This saves us from
                // allocating and garbage collecting many objects for files with
                // many items.
                user = dataFileReader.next(user);
                System.out.println("deserialized : "+user);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for example.I have to read consumer streaming data and decode each offset.

Comment: can we read schema from a file ?                 Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("src/avrto_schema.avsc"));